# Or-ing arrays of bools in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays of `bool`s in Swift, not necessarily of the same size, and would like to do an element-wise OR between them.
Consider, e.g.,

```
var array1 = [false, true, false, true, false, true]
var array2 = [true, true, false, false]
```

What I would like to do is apply `array2` as an OR-mask to a portion of `array1`.

If I were to transcribe `array2` into a portion of `array1`, I would simply do this

```
array1[0..<array2.count] = array2[0..<array2.count]
```

But I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
array1[0..<array2.count] ||= array2[0..<array2.count]
```

which of course does not compile because `||=` is not available.

An explicit solution is to iterate through the elements in a classical way:

```
for i in 0..<array2.count {
    array1[i] = array1[i] || array2[i]
}
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant, Swift-like (maybe faster?) solution.

Comment: If you know you will never have more than 64 entries in your array, I would suggest simply using two `Int64`s and a bitmask. Is this solution applicable to your usecase?

Comment: No, I can actually have millions of elements in the array. Would an array of 64-bit bitmasks make sense or be slower anyhow?

Comment: you can override an operator for doing that.

Comment: @Maiaux with millions of values, you would see large performance benefits by using an array of `Int64`s. Implementing such a datastructure is rather simple as well.

Comment: @DavidGanster Using arrays of `UInt64`s seems an order of magnitude faster for OR-ing the arrays. Reading a single "bit" in the array of `UInt64`s seems to take about the same time as in the array of `Bool`s. Writing a single bit seems 10% slower in the array of `UInt64`s, but that may depend on my specific implementation. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Swift-like" you mean a more declarative solution, you can:

1. `zip` the arrays
2. `map` the zipped tuples to produced an "or-ed" array
3. replace the slice in the first array

Here's how it would look like:

```
let oredArray = zip(array1, array2).map { $0 || $1 }
array1[0 ..< min(oredArray.endIndex, array2.endIndex)] = ArraySlice(oredArray)
```

This does, however, require `array1` to be mutable. Also, notice the use of `min()` – it's a safeguard against `array2` being longer than `array1`.

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for. However, this is 2 to 3 times slower than my explicit for loop. I guess zip comes with a heavy overhead.

Comment: @Maiaux have you had a time to benchmark [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41652557/4573247)? I speculate that the in-place replacement in my answer should be comparable to the explicit `for` loop, even though it also makes use of `zip`; I don't believe the `zip` comes with a great overhead, but possibly rather the new array instantiation (which is then used for replacement in `array1`) in the answer above.

Comment: @dfri I tried it now and it is actually the slowest approach. You are right about `zip`: it takes virtually no time. But `map` is slower than the classical `for` loop, and `foreach` is slower than `map`. With 10M elements, my approach takes 6.88 seconds, Sulthan's 11.69 (of which 8.68 for `map`) and yours 15.39 (almost entirely taken by `foreach`). Elegance and declarativity seem to have a cost...

Comment: @Maiaux thanks for the feedback, that's interesting. Just double-checking: you are benchmarking in a project set to build release mode (for compiler optimizations)? But generally I recognize what you describe: the classical for/while loop approaches (currently seems to) beat the functional ones.

Comment: @dfri I had simply used the default settings. With build release mode things change quite a bit: my approach is still the fastest if `array1` is entirely set to `false` (and `array2` is randomly populated with `true` and `false`), as I had done for simplicity: 0.021s vs 0.043s with your approach and 0.076s with Sulthan's approach, on 10M elements. But if `array1` is also random, yours is the fastest (0.044s), then mine (0.069s), then Sulthan's (0.077s). The compiler is possibly doing something clever behind the curtains of the `for` loop, which changes execution time so radically

Comment: @Maiaux Cool, I guess it should be expected that the `forEach` approach is comparable to the explicit `for` loop if the compilers is allowed to make smart optimizations. Would be interesting to test performance (random `array1`) if we modify our _"always assign even if value is unchanged"_ approach to only make an assignment in case the existing element is `false`. E.g., replace the content of my operator above with `zip(0..<lhs.count, rhs).forEach { if !lhs[$0] { lhs[$0] = $1 } }` (updated my answer to show this approach). They _might_ be equivalent due to optimizations, but I'm unsure.

Comment: @dfri I tried your new approach, and the conclusion seems to be that things are rather unpredictable wrt what the optimizer can do. If I start with `array1` containing only `false`, the timing is about the same as with your previous version (no improvement). Instead, with a random `array1` things get much worse, and your approach is the slowest (0.083 s for 10M elements)

Comment: @Maiaux maybe the `if` statements in the 2nd approach is somewhat slower, for some reason, than the `||` operator and an assignment (possible the assignment is optimized away if there will be no value update). Anyway, thanks for feedback and benchmarks!

Comment: @akashivskyy pdf

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why you can't define the operator by yourself, e.g:

```
let array1 = [false, true, false, true, false, true]
let array2 = [true, true, false, false]

func ||(lhs: Array<Bool>, rhs: Array<Bool>) -> Array<Bool> {
    let shorter: Array<Bool>
    let longer: Array<Bool>

    if lhs.count < rhs.count {
        shorter = lhs
        longer = rhs
    } else {
        longer = lhs
        shorter = rhs
    }

    let shorterProlonged = shorter + longer.suffix(from: shorter.count)

    return zip(shorterProlonged, longer).map { $0 || $1 }
}

print(array1 || array2)
```

Comment: The behavior for `||` on arrays of different size isn't obvious to me, so would see value in using a function with a representative name instead of an operator.

Comment: @zneak I just used what the OP requested but personally I would just extend the shorter array with `false` values.

Comment: @zneak Actually I used the hypothetical operator on array slices of the same size

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the global [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) function creates a truncated zipped sequence with a the length that is the shorter on of the two supplied sequences.

> If the two sequences passed to `zip(_:_:)` are different lengths, the
>   resulting sequence is the same length as the shorter sequence.

To zip the indices of the array being transcribed into with the elements of the array being transcribed from. E.g. to construct a custom in-place replacement infix operator:

```
infix operator ||=: AssignmentPrecedence

func ||=(_ lhs: inout [Bool], rhs: [Bool]) {
    zip(0..<lhs.count, rhs).forEach { if !lhs[$0] { lhs[$0] = $1 } }
    //or: zip(0..<lhs.count, rhs).forEach { lhs[$0] = lhs[$0] || $1 }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
// array to be transcribed _into_ longer than the array
// being transcibed from
var array1 = [false, true, false, true, false, true]
var array2 = [true, true, false, false]

array1 ||= array2
print(array1) // [true, true, false, true, false, true]

// array to be transcribed _into_ shorter than the array
// being transcibed from
array2 = [true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false]
array1 ||= array2
print(array1) // [true, true, false, true, true, true]
```

---

Note also the following valuable comment from @zneak:

> *"The behavior for `||` on arrays of different size isn't obvious to me,
>   so I think that it could be valuable to use a function with a
>   representative name instead of an operator."*

So you might want to considering implementing the logic above into a function with a semantically sound name rather than an operator.